# How to do data binding for particular columns in Dev Express XtraGridControl?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

In .net grid view Control we have a Property called "**DataPropertyName**" where we can specify column name which you want to bind

**example Code:**

```
dataGridView1.Columns[index].DataPropertyName=
myDataSource.Tables[index].Columns[index].ColumnName);
```

Any body please help me how to do this in DevExpress Extra Grid Control

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding Property on DevExpress columns is called `FieldName`